# String manipulation in mutate with stringr

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

So lets say that I want to locate a pattern in a string and if the pattern exists then I only keep the part of the string before the pattern. My problem is that if the pattern does not exist then it returns `NA` and the final result will be `NA`. I want it to return the original string when the pattern does not exist.

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
unique(iris$Species)
#> [1] setosa     versicolor virginica 
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica

test <- iris %>%
  mutate(Species = str_sub(Species, 1, str_locate(Species, "t")[,1] ))

head(test)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     set
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     set
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     set
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     set
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     set
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     set
tail(test)
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5    <NA>
#> 146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3    <NA>
#> 147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9    <NA>
#> 148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0    <NA>
#> 149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3    <NA>
#> 150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: What is the issue with the current solution

Comment: @akrun: I want it to return the original string when the pattern does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround with `str_remove`.  If the pattern is not found, it will return the original string.  Here, we are matching characters (`.*`) after the 't' character and if found, those characters are removed

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
test <- iris %>% 
          mutate(Species = str_remove(Species, "(?<=t).*")) 
head(test)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     set
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     set
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     set
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     set
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     set
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     set
tail(test)
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
#146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
#147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
#148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
#149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
#150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```